# PHP websocket | strange characters when sending data with high frequency

Tags: php, websocket, character

I have a javascript websocket client and a php websocket server. When I send a lot of data to the server with a loop, strange characters appear in the server window.

I send:

```
setInterval(function() {
    for (var i=1; i<=5; i++) {
        WS.send("0");
    }
}, 1000);
```

In server window:

```
Received [1]: 0╩┤&ψ╙]▬)╩Zόrcj
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0≤↓ [☺ψ╧
Received [1]: 0¶╞0UoL
§╧q←%ved [1]: 0Τ
Received [1]: 0b:Ρ"6Τι
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0&Ρ┼→↑αΫ
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0╦►╬┘Τ7■
Received [1]: 0SΖ╥m╬'έ
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0,!☼┘L╡?
Received [1]: 0L│%☼ΪH§
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0▀μpp┤A@
Received [1]: 0V[A√╚ύq
```

When I send data with lower frequency, everything is fine

I send:

```
setInterval(function() {
    WS.send("0");
}, 1000);
```

and in server window:

```
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
Received [1]: 0
```

**Why is this happening? Is this normal?**

Function used to unmask data:

```
function unmask($data) {
    $length = ord($data[1]) & 127;
    if($length == 126) {$masks = substr($data, 4, 4); $data = substr($data, 8);}
    elseif($length == 127) {$masks = substr($data, 10, 4); $data = substr($data, 14);}
    else {$masks = substr($data, 2, 4); $data = substr($data, 6);}
    $text = "";
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {$text .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];}
    return $text;
}
```

Here I receive the message:

```
while(socket_recv($client, $buffer, 2048, 0) >= 1) {
    $msg = unmask($buffer);
    echo "$msg\n";
}
```

Comment: my websocket server is written in php language

Comment: I mean, can you show us some code? It could be almost anything causing it.

Comment: Nagle's Algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm . You're getting multiple WS frames within a single TCP packet.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting multiple WebSocket frames in your packet due to [Nagle's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).  You're sending small messages so quickly that, to minimize network congestion, the client is holding on to data until it gets a confirmation from the server, or until a reasonable timeout has occurred.

To get around this, you would need to only take `$length` number of bytes off, then run your `unmask()` function on the remaining data.

Your code is also susceptible to oversized WebSocket frames being split among different packets; try sending more than 64KB of data in a message and see what happens. (You can go lower and see similar results; Ethernet has an MTU of 1500 bytes, but TCP itself has an MTU of 65536 bytes, so you will always see the effects of fragmentation when you send more than 64K.)

In my server, I have a buffer for each connected user that gets filled up until I have a complete WebSocket frame to deal with fragmentation, and I only pull off `$header_length + $message_length` worth of data off the front of that buffer at a time, in case there are multiple frames in that buffer.

Comment: Thank you, my friend. Because im not that advanced, can you write the "unmask" function? Will be easier for me to study this around because I don't understand these things 100%

Comment: For example, how can I get the $length value to take these bytes off

Comment: "If you build a man a fire, you warm him for a night. If you set a man on fire, you warm him for the rest of his life."  -- No. WebSockets is straightforward to implement, but it is not a "beginner" topic for PHP developers. If you need something that just works for a job you're getting paid for, go find an open source server. If you're trying to learn for the sake of learning, then remember that failure is an important part of learning, and the eventual success is made all the more valuable.

Comment: With that being said, the length of the message is contained in the frame.  Your unmask function is already pulling that value out.

Comment: @marirena And also, discussing the nitty gritty details of how to create a WebSocket server is beyond the scope of any one question and of this site.  If/when you get stuck again, feel free to ask more questions, or pop into the chat. (Tagging on this one, because I've finally gotten all that I want to say out.)