# PHP socket strange characters when sending data fast

Tags: php, sockets

I used this chat PHP app with sockets:
https://phppot.com/php/simple-php-chat-using-websocket/

But when I'm sending data really fast:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    websocket.send(JSON.stringify({ action: 'testtesttest' }));
}
```

I got strange characters like:

```
)›Ñ?‹[gÀV1“ÂHÈ™]a„“]g‹ÌpÈ’\`‹Úch‹Ž)‹Mw‹Ìg‹Úc"…Ò ôh‹Ž)‹”PfÇ„]a‹Ìg‹ÚcNÔÌC1ÇÂ1Ä•\1…ÂL1“» ?›ÌNÔ½EYÞ
```

They say [PHP websocket | strange characters when sending data with high frequency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32446637/php-websocket-strange-characters-when-sending-data-with-high-frequency) that it has something todo with the unmask method:

```
function unseal($socketData) {
        $length = ord($socketData[1]) & 127;
        if($length == 126) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 4, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 8);
        }
        elseif($length == 127) {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 10, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 14);
        }
        else {
            $masks = substr($socketData, 2, 4);
            $data = substr($socketData, 6);
        }
        $socketData = "";
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($data); ++$i) {
            $socketData .= $data[$i] ^ $masks[$i%4];
        }
        return $socketData;
    }
```

But I don't know what.

Can someone help me out?

Comment: The first snippet doesn't look like PHP... Anyhow, can you extract and provide a [mcve]? Also, make sure you check for errors where they don't raise exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

This has caught me out before. The issue is caused by more than one frame being sent by the client within the same TCP packet. This is done by the client for efficiency reasons.

In your unseal function, you are getting the `$length` variable, but never using it. To resolve the issue, truncate the `$data` variable by `$length` bytes, then use the remaining bytes to call the unseal function again.

This recursive calling will mean your unseal function might return more than one message - so you probably want it to return an array of strings.

EDIT: I typed up my findings here: https://github.com/g105b/text (and for fun, deployed the application at https://www.walloftext.art)

Comment: Just curious... Do you have a reference or some example where this is documented? It will make your answer more useful.

Comment: I noticed this when inspecting the connection in the network tab of the Firefox developer console. I was debugging my application because I too was noticing strange characters in the incoming messages. After noticing the length of the payload was larger than the length specified in the first byte, I realised that I could continue unmasking. Sorry that I haven't documented this anywhere, but I will put my thoughts together in a Github repo at some point, with some working examples.

Comment: @RyanVincent I typed up an article of what I've learnt here: https://github.com/g105b/text/

Comment: That looks really useful to understand what is going on. Thank you. :)